# I want to study the various usages of the 17th and 16th century verb "atone". Other than oed.com, where can I study this verb and adverb?

Tags: discussion, etymology, translation

I'm looking specifically for works that discuss the sense of a cessation of quarrels as found in oed.com's definition for the verb "atone":

1555   W. Waterman tr. J. Boemus Fardle of Facions i. vi. 92   Those battayles are attoned by the women..For when they be ones comen into the middle..the battaile sodenly ceaseth.

I would also be pleased to be pointed to a work that discusses or explores why the KJV bible translators stuck with atonement (Romans 5:11) when so many of their peers in the field of translation chose to use the traditionally accepted word "reconciliation" when rendering the Greek καταλλαγή into English.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The translators of KJV 1611 were elderly men whose use of English had been learned from equally elderly men, and the language chosen was already outdated by publication and yet, by this, it had an air of learned authority. I assume it was intentional.

Comment: [Christianity.SE](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22King+James%22+Bible+greek) might also be of help where translations are concerned

Comment: @Mari-LouA I'd suggest [hermeneutics.se] actually.

Answer (score 5):

For primary source research, *Early English Books Online* is an excellent resource for searching among a corpus of printed texts from the period. There are two free ways to access this: the [EEBO Text Creation Partnership](https://www.english-corpora.org/eebo/), which has basic search tools across the whole corpus of texts, and the more selective [EEBO corpus on the English Corpora site](https://www.english-corpora.org/eebo/) that has been tagged in such a way that you can search for things like parts of speech.

There is also a commercial version of [EEBO](http://eebo.chadwyck.com) (through ProQuest) that some libraries and individuals subscribe to. This site has a more comprehensive selection of images for each book, whereas EEBO-TCP relies on transcriptions. If you have access to it, absolutely use it.